# Enable 32-bit application preventing ASP.NET 2.0 app connecting to SQL server 2012

Tags: asp.net, iis, sql-server-2012

I'm migrating an old ASP.NET 2.0 app for a client from their old 32-bit windows server 2003 / SQL server 2000 machine to their new Windows server 2012 / SQL server 2012 machine.

I got everything loaded and working fine - website connects to SQL server and runs normally - except one of the import functions using a legacy Microsoft jet engine 4.0  was not working. After some more research, I have installed the legacy office 2007 drivers, and I also needed to set the application pool to enable 32-bit applications.

However, when I set the website to run at 32-bits, it bugs out because it is unable to connect to the 2012 database (the website loads fine, just the first function to access the database fails, and this is reflected in the logs I see). Please note - I have tested repeatedly and it is definitely this 32-bit setting that is the issue. With it set to false, it connects to SQL server and the whole website operates fine bar that import procedure. With it set to true (a prerequisite for the import procedure to work), the database connection fails and the site is inoperable.

Unfortunately the client does not have ready access to the source code (it was built such a long time ago) - all I have is the website pages and the binaries - and this is just a stop gap until a new system is developed.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which is exactly the error in log files?

Comment: It is just indicating that it cannot connect to the database and cannot find the table. I should have specified these are log files specific to the application, so the error message is not as verbose as it could be (the errors are captured, so it does not write to the Application event log). From my knowledge of the code (and the fact that it connects fine to the database when running under 64-bit), this is what is directing me to believe it is an error when connecting to the SQL server. I have checked that the connection string is using the named instance, not the IP address.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? Using a DSN that was created in the 64bit space and/or a driver that only exists in 32bit mode?

Comment: The system just connects using a connection string and ADO.NET. I do have access to change the connection string. No DSN setup - though I would be happy to try a DSN connection if I could then configure it in the connection string if this means I can connect to the database whilst the system runs under 32-bit. Please let me know the steps!

Comment: Any update on this? I have similar issues